# Is it necessary to register website on facebook, twitter or LinkedIn for og: tags

Tags: seo, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol, react-js

I have addded all og tags and twitter tags in my react website but facebook and linkedIn website debugger cannot get the tag. Is it necessary to register or claim domain website on Facebook and LinkedIn? And in twitter I got Error like this,

```
INFO:  5 metatags were found
ERROR: No card found (Card error)
WARN:  this card is redirected to https://www.website.com/
```

Comment: Please post the HTML  source containing the og: tags.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary to register your website to get opengraph-enabled links on those sites. All that's necessary is for the tags to be present.

My guess is that your tags are malformed. If you post a snippet of code containing your open graph tags, we might be able to point out the issue.